# How to increase Request line/fieldsize limit?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I want to encode a long Base64 encoded string within the URL.

Currently long URLs (over 300 chars) that are rewritten under mod-rewrite result in a forbidden(402) error.

If my request URL is 355 characters it results in error, however when I reduce it to 300 it works.

Is there a default value in the server that limits the request line size?

I couldn't find the LimitRequestLine/FieldSize directive anywhere in my server configuration.

Here is my rewrite rule:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^json/ base64json.php [L]
```

A URL looks something like this:

```
 http://sub.mydomain.com/json/longrandomnumbers?param=xxx
```

I wish to extract randomnumbers and param from the rewritten url, but it says forbidden permission denied, inside apache2 error log, it says:
Mon Mar 19 21:03:31.711559 2018] [core:error] [pid 20504] (36)File name too long: [client 167.220.24.128:45071] AH00036: access to /json/eyJldmVudHMiOlt7InNlc3Npb25JZCI6InMxNTAxMjY0OTIzeDYyZjg4MTNlNjkzMWM5eDU4MjQ0MjY2IiwiaW5zdGFudGlhdGlvbiI6IjkxMTMwMDQ3MTQ3OTE1ODgiLCJpbmRleCI6MCwiY2xpZW50VGltZXN0YW1wIjoxNTIwMzg3NTkwLjE2OSwibmFtZSI6ImNyZWF0aXZlTG9hZGVkIiwidmlld2FiaWxpdHkwME1lYXN1cmFibGUiOnRydWUsInZpZXdhYmlsaXR5NTAxTWVhc3VyYWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9XX0= failed (filesystem path '/var/www/track/json/eyJldmVudHMiOlt7InNlc3Npb25JZCI6InMxNTAxMjY0OTIzeDYyZjg4MTNlNjkzMWM5eDU4MjQ0MjY2IiwiaW5zdGFudGlhdGlvbiI6IjkxMTMwMDQ3MTQ3OTE1ODgiLCJpbmRleCI6MCwiY2xpZW50VGltZXN0YW1wIjoxNTIwMzg3NTkwLjE2OSwibmFtZSI6ImNyZWF0aXZlTG9hZGVkIiwidmlld2FiaWxpdHkwME1lYXN1cmFibGUiOnRydWUsInZpZXdhYmlsaXR5NTAxTWVhc3VyYWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9XX0=')
and
     failed (filesystem path

'/var/www/track/json/eyJldmVudHMiOlt7InNlc3Npb25JZCI6InMxNTAxMjY0OTIzeDYyZjg4MTNlNjkzMWM5eDU4MjQ0MjY2IiwiaW5zdGFudGlhdGlvbiI6IjkxMTMwMDQ3MTQ3OTE1ODgiLCJpbmRleCI6MCwiY2xpZW50VGltZXN0YW1wIjoxNTIwMzg3NTkwLjE2OSwibmFtZSI6ImNyZWF0aXZlTG9hZGVkIiwidmlld2FiaWxpdHkwME1lYXN1cmFibGUiOnRydWUsInZpZXdhYmlsaXR5NTAxTWVhc3VyYWJsZSI6ZmFsc2V9XX0=')

I tried to add RequestLine/FieldSize to apache2.conf, no use, wondering how to by pass the limit for the file system I use and why it's so annoying to check the length somehow before redirect to the correct path which is base64json.php, could I do it as a long parameter instead? It might be caused by ubuntu files system.

I am using Apache2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.02.

Comment: I've just tried a url that contained a parameter that's 1092 chars long on Apache 2.4.10 (pretty much default conf) on Debian 8.3 via a rewrite rule and my parameter came through fine.

Comment: Try it without the rewrite rule, just passing a long string as a parameter.  foo.php?bar=bazbazbaz..., does it still fall over?

Comment: I needed to push my parameter length to over 4000 chars at which point I get a forbidden.  If I go higher further I then get Request uri too long errors from apache.  That's via docker, on an underlying ext4 file system.

Comment: You are right,Thanks. I pulled it with mydomain/base64json.php?longercharactersandparameters, it does accept it, so what's wrong with my rewrite rule, plz see the rule above.

Comment: As said, I can use that rule (in a .htaccess) and it works for up to about 4000 chars with simple strings.

Comment: I changed it to .htaccess, but still forbidden, I think it's the file system problem, not sure why it check filesystem before it hits RewriteRule, maybe the url is an image.

Answer (score 0):

This must be defined before loading any Virtual Host.
Add this in yours `apache2.conf`, right.
Did you restarted apache daemon after edit?

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I did, but still the same error and limit's its length